# How to play Play a system sound with macOS SwiftUI

Tags: macos, audio, swiftui, system-sounds

I am trying to play a system sound with a MacOS SwiftUI application.
What I wish is just to play a system sound when an image appears...

My code (part of it) is the following

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
...
Image("OK Done")
   .resizable()
   .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
   .offset(x: 40, y: 0)
   .opacity(OKisVisible ? 1.0 : 0.0)
   .onAppear {
/*    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108)        This works on iOS only */
      AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1108)         // This does not work on macOS Ventura 13.2.1
   }
...
```

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Comment: This is macOS, not iOS - @Roj, it makes a big difference when it comes to System Sounds, so your comment is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple changes up the installed assets with each Mac OS version. Anything undocumented might not be reliable or approved for the Mac Store, as I understand. The only MacOS system sounds that can be used are those documented, [System Sounds in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audio_services/1405222-system_sounds), i.e. kSystemSoundID_FlashScreen and kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert.

The following is example code using one of those sounds:

```
import SwiftUI
import AudioToolbox

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("OK Done")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .onAppear {
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert))
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...YES, NOW, with your suggestion,  it work !